# Google Chrome is consuming a lot of CPU on a video call?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, video-streaming, cpu

We've been running a video application in a web browser and we are facing quite a lot complaints about the performance of the video calls.

90% of the complaints are when the user uses a virtual background and we use a library for that and it uses WebGL2 for the rendering.

We've performed the following options to debug the problem.

- Capturing a performance profile and we saw some long running tasks.
- Enabling the performance monitor to see the CPU consumption on the specific chrome tab which was running the video call and we sometimes see it's more than 90% but on the system level it's not.
- Enabling hardware acceleration.

We figured out that there is some issue with the library that we use but I want to workaround the problem in some way, until there is a fix available.

I'm also not quite sure if chrome does some resource saving within the tabs to not bombard the CPU usage on system level.

My question here is: Can we somehow workaround this problem by letting the chrome tab use more CPU when a specific tab is running a video call?

Or maybe some other approach which can improve the performance?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no information here to help debug this problem, so I don't really know what you want us to say.  Other than that... video takes a ton of CPU and that's the way it is.  Chrome doesn't always use the GPU... there are many blacklisted drivers and incompatibilities.  Take a look at `chrome://gpu/` and `chrome://media-internals/` and `chrome://webrtc-internals/`.

Comment: @Brad Sorry but I can't provide more information here as it also contain some organizational data. I've already checked these URLs to validate the hardware acceleration webgl etc. What exactly do you want me to check for incompabilities? Maybe it would be great if you can elaborate more with granular information.